# I'm looking for Audio Drama suggestions that have a good mix of music and sound design.

Tags: audio-drama, mixing, music, sound-design, dialogue

I have the good fortune to write music for a wonderfully produced audio drama that features compelling sound design, great acting with audio that's captured really well on location. Sometimes in post production, my music, in my biased opinion, does not hit the right level in the overall mix.

If there are any audio drama fans here, can you suggest some action-oriented audio dramas that have an impressive mix when it comes to dialogue, sound design and music simultaneously? I have a few programs from GraphicAudio. I've enjoyed 52 although at times, the mix felt overwhelming and in your face. Which, again, is just an opinion! They do great work overall. I was just wondering if anyone has suggestions for a mix that I can use for a benchmark.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't really heard any action-oriented ones myself, but Sue Zizza is one of the bigger producers of modern radio dramas. The last one I know of her doing is [The Witches of Lublin](http://www.thewitchesoflublin.com/stations.html). She doesn't have a personal/professional website that I know of other than that link above, but Googling her led me to [Radio Drama Revival](http://www.radiodramarevival.com/)...which might be a good starting point for research.

Comment: Actually, I am working with one of the good folks from Radio Drama Revival. The programs I've heard so far do not feature as much music as our program. However, I did get to listen to a Doctor Who Audio Drama that featured music at a significantly lower level in the mix, but it can still be appreciated. I'll try to aim for that level in my next submission.

Answer (score 1):

With radio you have no visual cues and clues as to what is going on, every thing is in the audio. So the problem we face in the mix, is if the music is too high the only thing that will cut through is the dialog, all the atmoses etc and most of the spot effects and foley are masked by the music, so although you may feel the music is not as loud as you would like, we have to balance all the layers to get a complete sound, to tell the story convincingly. Perhaps consider making sure your music has space in the appropriate places to allow the atmos tracks and spot effects to come through without having to dip the music so far.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out MEGA TALES http://megatales.tumblr.com.  It kind of reminds me of The Twilight Zone meets Are You Afraid of the Dark with a comedic twist.  Really funny stuff and really well produced.  Great sound mix use of effects, music, acting, etc.  Quality program that is always good for a laugh!

https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/mega-tales/id556744899?mt=2

http://megatales.bandcamp.com/

https://www.facebook.com/pages/MEGA-TALES/308489252545161

https://twitter.com/REALMegaTales

Answer (score 0):

http://paperradio.net is the thing I work on. I wouldn't make any claims on its quality - it's definitely a work in progress. But it's another thing to listen to and think about, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby series from ZBS has always had a healthy amount of music, mixed quite nicely in my opinion. Pretty much everything ZBS does has some musical material but Ruby seems to carry the most, off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Voices In The Wind Audio Theatre and their productions.
http://www.voicesinthewind.ca/

Answer (score 0):

Minister of Chance - ministerofchance.com
It's developed more like a movie sans visuals than regular audiodrama, but maybe it'll help.